# Расчёт количества цепочек

Tags: php, алгоритм

Доброго времени суток!
Есть последовательность: '**1**000**111**00**111**00**11**0**11**00**1111**' и т.д.

Нужно вычислить количество разных цепочек, т.е.

кол-во цепочек из 1-го элемента - 1,
кол-во цепочек из 2-х элементов - 2,
кол-во цепочек из 3-х элементов - 2,
кол-во цепочек из 4-х элементов - 1.

Имеется в виду непрерывная цепь единичек. 
Кол-во элементов в конкретной цепочке неизвестно.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$sequence = '1000111001110011011001111';
preg_match_all("/1+/", $sequence, $matches);
foreach ($matches[0] as $match) $result[strlen($match)]++;
echo '<pre>'; print_r($result);
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 1
    [3] => 2
    [2] => 2
    [4] => 1
)
```

Comment: Alexander Zonov, это просто гениально! Спасибо огромное! Ты нереально крут!

Comment: Ага, вот только если не будет отключен вывод предупреждений, то вместе с результатом, получите еще и пяток нотисов. Думаю, что тот, кто дал это задание, не будет в восторге.

Comment: Deonis, а почему должны быть нотисы? Если перед foreach поставить if(count($matches[0])), то никаких нотисов не будет. Само решение через регэкс очень изящное.

Comment: @waterman, [да неужели](http://ideone.com/Ky0Jal) ?

Comment: @Deonis, дело в том, что "Undefined offset" это чистое вранье, поскольку массивов в PHP нет, следовательно и никаких "offset" быть не может. Впрочем, вранье в PHP начинается прямо с самого названия.